# Scanf doesn't work properly in multiprocessing with mutex

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, scanf, mutex

I synchronize program with mutex which shared between parent and child process, but it works not as I expect, I expect: I type num and then output it and for another process the same, but works only one process.

minimal example of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// for multiprocessing
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
// for shared mutex
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_mutexattr_t mutexattr;

int main()
{
    pthread_mutex_t *shared_mutex;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexattr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &mutexattr);
    shared_mutex = (pthread_mutex_t *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(mutex), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0) {
        int num;
        pthread_mutex_lock(shared_mutex);
        printf("enter num for child: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(shared_mutex);

        pthread_mutex_lock(shared_mutex);
        printf("num in child: %d\n", num);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(shared_mutex);

        return 0;
    } else {
        int num;
        pthread_mutex_lock(shared_mutex);
        printf("enter num for parent: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(shared_mutex);

        pthread_mutex_lock(shared_mutex);
        printf("num in parent: %d\n", num);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(shared_mutex);

        wait(NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mutexattr);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    munmap(shared_mutex, sizeof(mutex));

    return 0;
}
```

in runtime it works infinitely:

[image]

Comment: You initialize `mutex`; you don't initialize `shared_mutex`.  You're unlucky that it isn't crashing.  Review that.  I would want distinct prompts and responses in the parent and child processes so that you can tell which one is working and which isn't.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` flag and [`pthread_mutexattr_setpshared()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared.html) functionsare supposed to make the relevant mutex accessible between processes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude hmm I saw this example in some site, ok, so how to synchronize two processes for I/O?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not sharing the actual `mutex` mutex across processes.  Instead you're sharing a blob of zero-initialized memory that isn't a mutex.

This code creates a mutex called `mutex` that's a local variable in `main()`:

```
pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexattr);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &mutexattr);
```

This code creates a ***completely unrelated*** blob of shared memory that holds a bunch of zero-initialized bytes that have nothing to do with any mutex, despite the name and type of the `shared_mutex` pointer variable:

```
pthread_mutex_t *shared_mutex;
    .
    .
    .
shared_mutex = (pthread_mutex_t *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(mutex),
    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
```

Those two areas of memory have absolutely nothing to do with each other other than being memory in the same process.  `mutex` refers to a mutex local to `main()`.  `shared_mutex` refers to a bunch of zeros.

The mutex needs to be created in the shared memory:

```
pthread_mutex_t *shared_mutex;
pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexattr);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
shared_mutex = (pthread_mutex_t *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(mutex),
    PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
pthread_mutex_init(shared_mutex , &mutexattr);
```

Cleanup of the mutex and shared memory is left as an exercise...